# Rejecting H0 for whole sample, while failing to reject H0 for its subsamples

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I investigate the influence of applied strategies (A and B) among two groups of users (novices N=16 vs experienced N=13) on their grades (0-100). For this purpose, I perform the Mann-Whitney test (also known as the Wilcoxon test for independent samples). I have an assumption that those applying strategy A will perform better than those applying B -> so one-tailed hypothesis. I run the test 3 times: per all users, per novices and per experienced users. For all users (U = 54, p = .013), so with α = 0.05 I reject H0. Even so, testing the groups separately: novices(U = 16, p = .057),   experienced (U = 12, p = .117) -> I can not reject H0.
I have difficulty understanding the reason for these results and interpreting them. Your help, please?

Comment: Note $54 > 16+12$.  You have smaller sample sizes for the types, so higher $p$ values is not a surprise, though there may be other things going on too.

Answer (score 0):

A p-value is dependent on how much evidence you have. For some effect size, you may deem the effect significant when you have lots of evidence to support it (a large sample size), but may not deem it significant with little evidence (a small sample size).

Even if the effect size is *truly identical* between the full population, among novices, and among experienced users, you are very likely to find a less significant p-value in a subset of the data than the full population, simply because you have a smaller sample size in the subset.

Seeing that there is a significant difference between A and B in the full population indicates you have sufficient evidence to reject the hypothesis that A performs no better than B. Seeing that significance disappear in the subset populations doesn't necessarily mean that the effect of A vs. B is any different in the subset, it just means you don't have sufficient evidence to make that conclusion.

Imagine I have 500 people flip a coin twice each, and see that all 1000 flips resulted in heads - this is obviously very good evidence that the coin is biased. Now I look at the subset consisting of the two flips conducted by Bob, and see that both turned up heads - from those two flips alone, I can't reliably conclude that the coin is biased. This is not inconsistent with the full population result, it just represents a lack of evidence in the subset rather than a change in the underlying odds.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! This means that I really can reject H0 for the whole dataset.  But now, when my conclusion is right for the whole population, there is still no sufficient evidence to make any conclusion for subsets separately. For example, if I will have more students and more novices in the future, it may happen that I reject H0 for one subset and do not reject it for another subset or reject H0 for both of them.